# Can I specify location of Application.FileDialog in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access pop-up form (Auto Center=Yes) with buttons on it to ask the user to select specific files to be brought into Access tables. The code behind the button calls a function, `getfileName()`, in a Module, which uses the `Application.FileDialog` object to create a form which the user will use to navigate to the appropriate folder to select the file. The full path to the file is then assigned to the function and this is used in the form code in a `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` line of code. This all works just fine so the functionality is not in question. One button has the user get one file, and the dialog box is centered in the screen, just as the form is. The second button has the user get two files; the first dialog box is centered, but the second dialog box is located at the upper left corner of the screen. I would like all dialog boxes to be centered on the screen but the file dialog box object does not seem to have any properties like the Form object does, such as 
`Auto Center`. I have not found anything in online documentation that would help me keep the dialog box centered when it is an `Application.FileDialog` object. Any pointers?

Here is the function:

```
Global path As String

Function getFileName(xMessage As String) As String

Dim fDialog As Object

Dim varFile As Variant
Dim importFile As String


' Set up the File Dialog.
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog

    ' Don't allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    ' Make the path directly to the folder where the dated folders are located
    ' For the first time through, the global variable path="", so assign the parent folder. After that,
    ' path is assigned the parent folder of the files being used.
    If Len(path) = 0 Then
        .InitialFileName = "\\server\share$\Parent Directory\Directory\"
    End If

    ' Set the title of the dialog box.
    If xMessage = "" Then
      .Title = "Please select the new file"
    Else
      .Title = xMessage
    End If

    ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.XLSX"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
    ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
    ' False, the user clicked Cancel.

    If .Show = True Then

         'Loop through each file selected (there is only one) and add it to our list box.
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
            importFile = varFile
        Next
        'Set the file name selected to the function name
        getFileName = importFile
    Else

         ' MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
         getFileName = ""
    End If

    'Save directory to global variable "path"
    path = getDirectoryPath(getFileName)

End With

Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: From what I can see, the answer is "No" to being able to directly specify the location.  But you mentioned it is centered in the "one file" button case. Is this button on a floating / movable / pop-up form?  Also, when you say the other button gets two files, you mean it calls getFileName() twice, one after the other?  Is this other button also on a movable form?

Comment: Hi @CPerkins - thanks for your questions. Yes, the form that contains both of the buttons in question is a Pop-up form with Auto Center=Yes. I added text in the original question to clarify this. And yes, the first button calls getFileName() just once and the second button calls that function twice, one after the other, in order to retrieve the file path and name for two files.

Comment: From my quick testing, I perceive that the FileDialog automatically "centers" itself with its "parent" form (the form which calls it)--the last Access form which has focus.  My guess is that the second call is happening after the primary Access form has already lost the focus so that the second call is not done in the same context as the first.  Perhaps if you can explicitly reset the focus back to the form between calls to get the second file it will also center that .  It's a dubious attempt to leverage automatic behavior in Access.

Comment: Since nobody else seems to be contributing, I'll at least mention that it is possible to call native Windows APIs to call standard file dialogs.  I have seen code to do this, but don't use it and would have to look it up myself.  Perhaps searching for "Access windows dialog api or code"... something similar.  I think in that way you can better control all aspects of the dialog windows, including placement on the screen.  Good luck.

Comment: @CPerkins I've thought about attempting to use the Windows calls (I've  seen mentions of "hwnd" in some other forums online) but I think I'll stick with leveraging native Access features for now. After all, I'm not trying to become a Windows programmer. I think I'll try the suggestion of resetting focus to the form. The other one I could try would be to create another form that replicates what `Application.FileDialog` does, which would give me more control as well. Thanks for your comments. At least I'm pretty sure I wasn't missing something.